# C# Inheritence Issue with new keyword

Tags: c#, inheritance, new-operator

I want to override the `Body` member in a `MailMessage` class so that it has essentially a Header and Footer.

I've extended the MailMessage class like this;

```
public class XMessage : MailMessage
{

private string header;
private string footer;
private string xbody;

new public string Body //hides MailMessage.Body
{
 get
  {
    return header + xbody + footer;
  }
}

////.....

}
```

When passing the `XMessage` to an `SmtpClient`'s `.Send(MailMessage m)` however, the body is blank. `MailMessage.Body` is not marked for overriding, but how can I get this behaviour from an extended class?

Comment: `Body` is not a virtual property, so this won't work.  Use your class to create a `MailMessage` with the Body set as desired.  Don't try to inherit from `MailMessage`.

Answer (score 3):

As you are observing, method hiding is not the same as overriding. As `SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage m)` is expecting a `MailMessage` it will use the implementation of `Body` defined in the `MailMessage` class.

As mentioned by Amy in the comments, this situation would be better suited to composition rather than inheritance.

An example:

```
public class XMessage
{
    private string header;
    private string footer;
    private string xbody;

    public MailMessage GetMailMessage()
    {
        return new MailMessage
        {
             Body = header + xbody + footer
             // set other properties
        };
    }
}
```